Return statement doesn't execute in React
My return statement on line 12 doesn't execute (all the rest executes fine). What is the problem?
I am calling handlesubmit function from another component and know that it is being called (console.log on line 9 executes fine).
import { useState } from 'react';
import SearchMovies from './components/SearchMovies';
import PlayTrailer from './components/PlayTrailer';

function App() {
    const [movieName, setMovieName] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (movie) => {
        console.log('movie submitted', movie); // This executes.
        setMovieName(movie);

        return <div>THIS DOESN'T EXECUTE!!!</div>; // This doesn't execute
    };

    return <div>
        <SearchMovies onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </div>
}

export default App;

Output

What behavior are you expecting?  Does the SearchMovies component do anything with the result from the onSubmit function, or is it just passed through to a DOM event handler?

The thing is that, in React, event handler functions (like handleSubmit) don't return JSX directly. They perform some action (updating the state with setState), and then the component's return function is the one that will render JSX.
Instead of trying to return JSX from handleSubmit, update the state (movieName) and use that in the main component.
Example
import { useState } from 'react';
import SearchMovies from './components/SearchMovies';
import PlayTrailer from './components/PlayTrailer';

function App() {
    const [movieName, setMovieName] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (movie) => {
        console.log('movie submitted', movie); 
        setMovieName(movie); 
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <SearchMovies onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
            {movieName && <div>Movie submitted: {movieName}</div>}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;

